MySQL 8.0 fails to store 5.7-allowed symbols (Incorrect string value, Error 1366)
I'm upgrading MySQL 5.7 server to 8.0 with a bunch of user-input data that sometimes contain "malformed" unicode characters like x'eda0bdedb98f'. The latter seems to be 2 UTF-16 characters 0xD83D 0xDE4F (4 bytes) of 'Folded Hands'-emoji encoded into 2 utf8mb3 characters (6 bytes).
This service correctly decodes the emoji, while the others consider it to be a wrong unicode character.
Problem
This symbol can be inserted into MySQL 5.7 table, but fails to insert into MySQL 8.0 table. Depending on sql_mode insert either fails or proceeds with a truncated string. Thus mysqldump + restore produces inconsistent data. The inplace upgrade works fine but I still cannot manipulate (insert/update) these characters. Changing the charset/collation doesn't help.
Question
Is that possible to force MySQL 8.0 to store "malformed" unicode characters like MySQL 5.7 does?
Steps to reproduce
Run latest MySQL 5.7 in Docker:
docker run --rm --name percona57 -e MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=1 percona:5.7 --character_set_server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_general_ci &
docker exec -ti --user root percona57 mysql --default-character-set=utf8mb4

Run latest MySQL 8.0 in Docker:
docker run --rm --name percona80 -e MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=1 percona:8.0 --character_set_server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_general_ci &
docker exec -ti --user root percona80 mysql --default-character-set=utf8mb4

Execute SQL commands (on both 5.7 and 8.0):
SET names utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%char%';
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%collat%';
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode';
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS test DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;
SHOW CREATE DATABASE test \G
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.t1 (id int unsigned auto_increment primary key, text varchar(255)) CHARSET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;
SHOW CREATE TABLE test.t1 \G
INSERT INTO test.t1 (text) VALUES (concat('aaa', x'eda0bdedb98f', 'bbb'));
SHOW WARNINGS;
SELECT *, hex(text) FROM test.t1;

Results from MySQL 5.7:
<...>
mysql> INSERT INTO test.t1 (text) VALUES (concat('aaa', x'eda0bdedb98f', 'bbb'));
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT *, hex(text) FROM test.t1;
+----+--------------+--------------------------+
| id | text         | hex(text)                |
+----+--------------+--------------------------+
|  1 | aaa������bbb     | 616161EDA0BDEDB98F626262 |
+----+--------------+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Results from MySQL 8.0:
<...>
mysql> INSERT INTO test.t1 (text) VALUES (concat('aaa', x'eda0bdedb98f', 'bbb'));
ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect string value: '\xED\xA0\xBD\xED\xB9\x8F...' for column 'text' at row 1
mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;
+-------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                                                                          |
+-------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Error | 1366 | Incorrect string value: '\xED\xA0\xBD\xED\xB9\x8F...' for column 'text' at row 1 |
+-------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT *, hex(text) FROM test.t1;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

Execution log for both MySQL 5.7 and 8.0 + SHOW VARIABLES statement: https://pastebin.com/MK0KUaV1

@AlessandroCattaneo - How much RAM on the machine?

Only one query per hour??

thread_stack is unusually high.  Did you change that?  Why?  Did you change other settings?

"How much RAM on the machine" - 4GB RAM, but both MySQL instances in Docker containers use only 15% of that.
"Only one query per hour?" - This is not a production instance. It's just two Docker containers simplified enough to display the issue persistently.
"Did you change other settings?" - That's default settings for official Percona MySQL Docker containers. I changed only charset and collation. You can see that in Steps to reproduce section and try it yourself.
